# SQL JOIN with multiple rows conditionally

Tags: php, sqlite, join

I have 2 tables in a SQLite database that I am accessing it via PHP
This is sample data, it is enough to describe what I want to do but not why.
Lets call these tables: `TableA`, `TableB`, and `TableC`

```
------------------------
|  Unique_ID  |  Name  |
------------------------
|  1          | Sam    |
------------------------
|  2          | Bob    |
------------------------
|  3          | Jill   |
------------------------

*Assume more rows for other possible foreign keys below
--------------------------------------------
|  Unique_ID  |  Foreign_Key  | Time_Stamp |
--------------------------------------------
|  1          | 1             | 1495298339 |
--------------------------------------------
|  2          | 1             | 1495298350 |
--------------------------------------------
|  3          | 1             | 1495298365 |
--------------------------------------------
```

What I want in my output would be something line this

```
------------------------------------
|  Name  | First_Time |  Last_Time |
------------------------------------
|  Sam   | 1495298339 | 1495298365 |
------------------------------------
|  Jill  | 1495298787 | 1495298805 |
------------------------------------
```

Basically I want to pull the fist and last time stamp into the 1st table, but I am not sure how to do a join line this or if it is even possible, multi-layered select queries with limited results of 1?
I am hoping there is a way to avoid looping through each value in `TableA` and making two separate queries to get the first (lowest) and last (highest) `Time_Stamp` in `TableB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a join between the first table and a processed version of the second table. The second table is a group by using the `Foreign_Key`, and the computed values are the minimum and maximum of `Time_Stamp`. Something like this:

```
select A.Unique_Id, B.First_Time, B.Last_Time
from TableA as A
join (
    select Foreign_Key, min(Time_Stamp) as First_Time, max(Time_Stamp) as Last_Time
    from Table B
    group by Foreign_Key
) as B
on A.Unique_Id = B.Foreign_Key
```

Comment: Would the other 2 competing answers be more efficient since they are only a single selection? Since your answer more accurately does what was asked by using `AS` while also given tables names I will give you get the accepted answer.

Comment: The performance should be the same, thanks to the query optimizer generally being good. But if it was not, it would be better to first do the group by, and reduce the very big `TableC` to a smaller table, with one entry for each user, _and only then_ do the join between two similarly sized tables. If one first does the join, one gets a table the size of `TableC`, with possibly many rows because of the join, which then must be reduced to a smaller size.

Comment: Assuming `TableB` had a 4th column (lets call it `Location_ID`) is there a way to pull said column where the `Time_Stamp` is min and max as there own column in this same query?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.Name, MIN( table2 .Time_Stamp ) AS firstTime, MAX( table2 .Time_Stamp ) AS lastTime
FROM  `table1` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.Unique_Id = table2.Unique_Id
GROUP BY table1.Unique_Id
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TableA.name, MIN(TableB.timeid), MAX(TableB.timeid) FROM TableA

INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.TableA_id 

GROUP BY TableB.TableA_id
```